# No category listed while publishing an article in front-end

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end

I'm having a strange issue - No matter with what user I login in my front-end Joomla site (even administrator) and try to add an article and then press button 'publishing', I do not see any category to choose from, it is all blank.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the screenshot, it's not only the category drop-down, but all the drop-down elements (status, featured, access etc).

I would guess that this might be a CSS issue with your template.
The only way to tell is by checking with the dev tools in your browser. **Right click on the drop-down area**- choose **"Inspect Element"** in and check for the following:

1. First see if there are any JS errors.
2. Try to identify in the source code, the content for these drop-downs, if it's there.
3. Check the CSS rules that apply to the drop-downs and play with it, in order to give it more space.

One quick way to see if it's Template related, you can change the front-end template - switch it to the default Protostar template and try again.

If the site is live and you don't want to make this change visible to everybody, create a new test article - assign it to a hidden menu item,   where only you will know, then assign to this menu item the Protostar template. and navigate there in the front-end and try to edit it.

If you find out that it's the template that causes this, contact the template developer regarding this issue.